# (Python) Non-linear regression of a multi-step fitting function and image similarity deduction

Tags: python, image-processing, blender, similarity, non-linear-regression

I am trying to find a physical position of an object with respect of a camera given the textured 3D model.

Suppose that you have a cylinder with a random texture painted on it, have it 3D scanned and also have an image of that object captured by a camera with a known focal length and pixel information (the intrinsic properties are known).

The rough position of the camera with respect of the cylinder is known along with the rough object orientation.

I am planning to use some sort of regression algorithm program to deduce the position of the object (x, y, z, rot_x, rot_y, rot_z) by using a similarity score.

My plan is to do the following:

- Set the camera to be at (0, 0, 0) in blender and import the 3D model with the rough position and orientation into blender.
- Convert the blender 3D model to a value of brightness (the image is a grayscale picture) for different coordinates
- Multiply the coordinates with a calibration matrix (this is exactly known because we know the intrinsic properties of the camera)
- Plot the new points with the brightness and compare it with the image captured by the camera.

I have two questions regarding this problem:

- What is the best library to use to do the regression?
- What is the best method to compare the two images that considers things like exposure and glare?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have read some documentations on sklearn library, but it seems like most of the stuffs there are used to do regression on plot fits, so I am not sure if those are applicable to my case.